# Getting error while copying the file from linux Local file system to HDFS

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

Its single node cluster while i'm starting i'm not getting any issue , I chekced the logs also for all daemons.

But while i'm copying the data from my local linux file system to HDFS file system its throwing an exception saying ;
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50010

Please find the attached log ;

```
 2014-07-08 15:56:28,342 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Does not contain a valid host:port authority: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50010
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.createBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3629)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)

2014-07-08 15:56:28,342 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for blk_3686864267613252482_3024 bad datanode[0] nodes == null
2014-07-08 15:56:28,342 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/tmp/hadoop-user1/mapred/system/jobtracker.info" - Aborting...
2014-07-08 15:56:28,342 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Writing to file hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hadoop-user1/mapred/system/jobtracker.info failed!
2014-07-08 15:56:28,343 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: FileSystem is not ready yet!
2014-07-08 15:56:28,351 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Failed to initialize recovery manager. 
java.io.IOException: Could not get block locations. Source file "/tmp/hadoop-user1/mapred/system/jobtracker.info" - Aborting...
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.processDatanodeError(DFSClient.java:3270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2200(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2987)
2014-07-08 15:56:29,352 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Retrying...
```

Comment: From Rajn (not enough rep) : Can you please run command `hadoop dfsadmin -report` and paste the output here?

Comment: Configured Capacity: 236225449984 (220 GB)
Present Capacity: 213673410560 (199 GB)
DFS Remaining: 213673381888 (199 GB)
DFS Used: 28672 (28 KB)
DFS Used%: 0%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Name: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 236225449984 (220 GB)
DFS Used: 28672 (28 KB)
Non DFS Used: 22552039424 (21 GB)
DFS Remaining:213673381888(199 GB)
DFS Used%: 0%
DFS Remaining%: 90.45%
Last contact: Wed Jul 09 10:55:07 IST 2014

Answer (score 0):

Check your mapred-site.xml. It should have valid tracker entry in it. Of course host and port values should be changed according to your system.

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>host:port</value>
</property>
```

Comment: As Özgür Eroğlu answer would solve your issue .Use either your system's IP address or the loopback address.

Comment: This is the entry in mapred-site.xml :

<property> 
<name>mapred.job.tracker</name> 
<value>localhost:9001</value> 
</property>


 My cluster set up is in Linux (Ubuntu) machine , i'm using putty from windows to access it .
Should i mention the IP address to the linux machine in place of localhost?

Comment: Changing the the host parameter to your external IP just enables remote access to jobtracker, but as you are running a single node setup it is not so important here, localhost should do the job. The problem may be that you used /tmp for dfs.data.dir , which is cleared after a reboot, so hdfs could not be recovered. Try with setting the data dir to something else, reformat it and try to restart.